# how can I use framework 7 view inside of wrapper

Tags: html-framework-7

if I try to wrap a div around this code:
For example:

```
<div class=“my-wrapper”>
  <div class=“views”>
  <!— Your main view —>
    <div class=“view view-main”>
    <!— Pages —>
      <div class=“pages”>
      <div class=“page” data-page=“home”>
         …framework 7 code…
      </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

it stops working completely. Anyone run into the same problem? How can I utilize framework 7 UI from inside of my app which is done in bootsrtap. I need to be able to combine both

Comment: Looking at your code, I cannot directly tell you what is going on, but I CAN tell you that Bootstrap and Framework7 can be combined. I have done this in a project.

Comment: what I mean is as soon as I put a wrapper around <div class=“views”>...some fm7 html code...</div> framework 7 stops working completely.

Comment: can you please post any quick example of how you were able to integrate framework 7 with bootstrap. Specifically I'm interested in seeing how you were able to insert framework 7 html code inside bootstrap's <div class=row><div class="col-md-12">...</div></div>

Comment: You can manipulate the html code without using the `<div class=“my-wrapper”>`. Refer to this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/timverwaal/bjbrtybg/

Comment: Tim V, thanks for your response on this. But what I really want actually is be able to call framework 7 view from inside of bootstrap template. 

For instance I have a an app done in bootstrap so I want to integrate some of the framework 7 features from inside of <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">....framework 7 view goes here....</div></div> But as soon as I put framework 7 html code there it stop working. It seems that framework 7's <div class="view></div>" does not like to be put inside of any kind of outer <div> because it stops working.. hope this makes sense..

Comment: Can you be more specific then... I don't see what the problem is...;(

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your help though, so here is the link to the working version of framework 7 contact list: http://aliyeff.com/framework7/

and here is the link to the bootstrap version of the same contact list, in this version I call contact list from inside of bootstrap template: http://aliyeff.com/framework7/bootstrap/bootstrap.html

Comment: note how it does not work in bootstrap's version it is because framework 7 does not seem to like to have any divs around it, specifically where the view starts <div class="view"> It does not like any divs before that "view". do that make sense? Bootstrap itself has nothing to do with this problem.